# Search text file returns a number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to search this text file but it returns a number, The code will not work it just returns a number

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            document.getElementById("textSection").innerHTML = allText;
        }
    }

    rawFile.send();
}

var str = readTextFile("testing.txt");
var n = str.search("Testing Search");
</script>
```

Comment: You realize that AJAX is asynchronous right? You're searching something that probably hasn't been returned yet.

Answer (score 0):

`readTextFile` call is asynchronous. You can't get `str` instantly. You should use callback. So you will be able do something with text only when response is received.

Example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readTextFile(file, callback)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            document.getElementById("textSection").innerHTML = allText;
            callback(allText); // call your function passing received text into it
        }
    }

    rawFile.send();
}

readTextFile("testing.txt" function(myStr) {
    // You will get here when response is received
    var n = str.search("Testing Search");
    alert(n);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because Ajax requests are [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393751/what-does-asynchronous-means-in-ajax). You should do it like this:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            document.getElementById("textSection").innerHTML = allText;
            callback(allText);
        }
    }

    rawFile.send();
}

readTextFile("testing.txt", function(text)
{
    var n = text.search('Testing Search');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `readTextFile` function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it will return nothing, and when you do `var str = readTextFile("testing.txt");`, `str` will be always `undefined`.

Besides that, the `XMLHttpRequest` in the way you're using is an asynchronous operation, and then, you won't be able to return the text received from the file.

So, you must comprehend that you'll need to do something different. For example, a callback function:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            document.getElementById("textSection").innerHTML = allText;
            callback(allText);
        }
    }

    rawFile.send();
}
```

And then, you'll use it like:

```
readTextFile("testing.txt", function(str) {
    var n = str.search("Testing Search");
});
```