# jquery ajax isn't working on the correct order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load from a `PHP` file using `ajax`, some `JSON` objects but my problem is that my `javascript`code is not working on the correct order. Here is my code:

```
var requests;
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
         url: "test2.php", 
         success: function(result){
         requests = JSON.parse(result);
         alert(requests);
         }
       });
   })
});
alert(requests);
```

[Here is the first alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXqTr.png)  i'm getting on page load and [here is the second alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG4wA.png)

My question is why the alert in the last line is executed before the ajax

Note: this is a small example of my project, my real error is that i cannot load some arrays i need using ajax, because it shows as undefined at console, even if the ajax is in the beginning of the script.

Comment: because first one needs time to load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Because it's *asynchronous* - ie starts the ajax request, then carries on before the request has completed.   Even more so, your 2nd alert runs before the `$(document).ready()` fires, which is an event that occurs later, when the document is ready.

Comment: better you try using the `complete` handler in `$.ajax`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid this is to create a function in which second alert would be placed. And call this function inside ajax call's success method.
e.g.

```js
ajax({
...
success: function(){
...
secondAlert();
};
...
});

function secondAlert(){
alert("alert after jax call");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

try this cod for ajax call with php

```js
 $.ajax({
  type: "method", // post or get
  url: "file url",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
 
  },
  error: function(){

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As for

> My question is why the alert in the last line is executed before the ajax

AJAX is an acronym for ***Asynchronous*** JavaScript and XML. The keyword here is asynchronous. AJAX sends the HTTP request and keeps executing the code in async fashion. The callback function of the AJAX request is executed **after** the request is finished and the corresponding response has been received. More info is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393751/what-does-asynchronous-means-in-ajax)